# How do I apply the changes from systemctl preset-all automatically without a reboot

Tags: systemd

systemctl preset-all changes which services are enabled or disabled.  How can I (automatically) start and stop services to get the current machine into sync with the presets without manually starting and stopping services myself.

The aim is to get the machine into a state after running preset-all without a reboot that is the same as the state of the machine after a reboot.

e.g. if I enable service X in the presets and X wasn't previously running then I'd like it to start.

Comment: In principle, `systemctl isolate` your desired target graphical.target / multi-user.target or just default.target, which is symlinked to whichever you default to at boot time.  In practice, `isolate` is a bag of horrors, it manages to kill gui sessions somehow among other things.  AFAIK there is no good way to do what you want.  Don't use presets if this is what you want; it's why Debian hasn't converted to rely on them despite multiple references to Debian in the documentation for presets.  Don't use isolate, or be prepared for it to blow up.

Comment: It's possible `systemctl isolate multi-user` is _somewhat_ less buggy.  If you're using a gui, you might try that, and then follow up with `systemctl isolate graphical.target`.  And then you _know_ bad things will likely happen to your gui, so you'll be running it from a text console or remote login.

Comment: Righto.. that's very interesting.  This is for a headless box but I don't like what I hear.  Thanks for the hard-to-find info...